# How i can get values of multi select in react-select

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm trying to get values from react-select  (multiselect) when the form submitted
I think I'll get an array of the options that've been selected

```
import React from 'react';

import Select from 'react-select';
import { colourOptions } from '../data';

export default () => (
  <Select
    defaultValue={[colourOptions[2], colourOptions[3]]}
    isMulti
    name="colors"
    options={colourOptions}
    className="basic-multi-select"
    classNamePrefix="select"
  />
);
```

Comment: The component probably have a ```onChange``` props. Try to add ```onChange={(e) => console.log(e)``` or ```onChange={(e) => console.log(e.target.value)``` to check the value.

Comment: i tried it but i'm getting Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'name')

Comment: Can you send what you wrote? Seems you're doing ```something.name``` with ```something``` undefined.

Comment: is this how options must be?const options = [
    { value: 'chocolate', label: 'Chocolate' },
    { value: 'strawberry', label: 'Strawberry' },
    { value: 'vanilla', label: 'Vanilla' },
];